# Dynamic recompilation on the same architecture

Tags: assembly, compilation

I know that dynamic recompilation can be used to translate instructions for one architecture to another during execution. But can it be used to optimize a program on the same architecture? If I write a poorly optimized assembly language program, can I use a dynamic recompiler to make it run faster than native speeds?

Comment: This is one of the ideas behind a JIT compiler or the late AOT compilers (i.e. compile when it hits the users system but not before).

Comment: I vaguely remember reading somewhere about this being tried experimentally. but I don't know if its ever gone beyond that. Dynamic recompilation from the native architecture to the native architecture does happen in practice with various software PC emulators (eg. DOSBox or QEMU) but programs don't run faster as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to create code that runs faster than native speed, as the fastest code possible still runs at native speed only. :)

If you mean "faster than the original code", then yes, it's possible to create tool with such purpose, but it will be quite difficult to make it practical and successful.

Reasoning:

With native-compiled languages like C++, by compiling the original source the compiler has many strong hints about the original intent of programmer, and their optimizer can be much more aggressive, not blindly translating everything char by char into machine code, but producing just code which holds up to the language definition (ie. omitting whole function call, when the result is not used, and there's no side effect of function execution).

Once you would try to optimize the native machine code itself only, you wouldn't have that additional context. So your new optimized code must mimic the original code in every aspect, down to all side effects and memory modifications.

At that point you are down to only some very minor optimizations, like register reallocation, instruction reordering, occasionally few instruction replacement with faster alternative, etc.

A modern x86 CPU is actually doing lot of that on it's own during execution, as the x86 original CISC-like instruction set is not implemented directly on the chip, but it gets translated into internal RISC-like micro-instructions, registers being aliased, and everything being reordered, executed in parallel when possible, with branch predictions speculative fetch-ahead, etc... A modern x86 CPU is like machine in machine, so it's actually doing probably half of what is possible in your approach by itself.

The other half is probably very difficult to compute for program anyway, so tool designed in your way would probably just save that internal x86 optimization hassle, making the machine code more target platform friendly, but gaining only marginal additional performance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of such a tool, very unlikely to exist, and even more unlikely to improve the speed of an already native program.

What could be done realistically on the other hand:

1. disassemble the program using IDAPro or other
2. identify code & data sections (this is important and tedious)
3. save as ASM
4. try to assemble it with a good assembler with all optimizations turned on
5. you can even try to profile the program, add new features, and manually optimize things now that you (almost) have the source

Step 2 is crucial, because failing to do so (marking data as real data) would be fatal to the program when optimizer is on: the optimizer would interpret data as instructions and would optimize them, resulting in different data!

Of course, failing to identify code as real code would be less of an issue, but you lose the ability to reassemble it more efficiently.

That method could help to improve, say, old-C compiled programs when optimization was not on or not very good. But a good job would require manually identifying the parts where the program wastes time. Assemblers can only perform local optimizations.

Comment: "good assembler with all optimizations turned on" ... well, I don't think any classic Assembler has any serious optimizations. They tend to compile the written assembly 1:1 to machine code instructions (except some macro-like expansions, but then as programmer you can always guess the resulting machine code exactly by reading only the source, so there's no "intelligence" involved).

Comment: not true, I saw some compilers generating things (in 68000) like `move.l  #0,D0` where a `moveq #0,d0` would be shorter and faster. An assembler processing those lines could make the substitution. But maybe that's a corner case.

Comment: Compiler and assembler are two different pieces of SW. I can easily see how compiler is doing optimizations as much as it could, but I would refrain from using Assembler with such feature (without some full control over it). If you write in your .asm "move.l", it should compile to "move.l", not "move.q".

Comment: Most 68k assemblers do that when optimization is enabled. You can enable such or such optimization as will. They also zap branches when not needed (unconditional branch to the next instruction), adjust branch size, etc... But maybe I'm speaking from my 68k point of view and it's less applicable to the intel architecture.

Comment: "...unlikely to improve the speed of an already native program". The OP is not clear and "maybe" you don't know WHERE is the problem of intepreted instruction versus native instruction e.g. in emulation. An emulator of some CPU written in C and compiled on x86 architecture is a "native" application. If you use dynamic recompilation on the same emulator on the same architecture you'll get a great speed improvement because the interpreted instruction of your emulator is converted to native code only one time and then cached for re-use